# Missing BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I just installed Grails, and I'm new to this framework. I can't find BuildConfig.groovy in my grails-app/conf/ directory. Am I suppose to generate it? Here is my env:

```
grails> exit 
| Grails Version: 3.0.1
| Groovy Version: 2.4.3
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_45
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using Grails 3.x which is built on Gradle and no longer uses the older `BuildConfig.groovy` for dependency management.

I recommend you read the official [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#gradleBuild) regarding Gradle and the new build system for Grails 3.0+.